# GSON does not return JSON key

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON to convert objects into JSON. I have this:

```
String name = "MyName";
```

and I use the following statement to convert it to json:

```
print(new Gson().toJson(name));
```

and the output is : `"MyName"`
How can I make it print in this way:

```
{"name":"myName"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

```
class YourClass {
    private String name;

    // getters and setters...
}

YourClass object = new YourClass();
object.setName("MyName");
print(new Gson().toJson(object));
```

And using JsonObject:

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.addProperty("name", "MyName");
print(new Gson().toJson(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
    String name = "myName";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(new Test()));
    }
}
```